# finding hfe using 8051

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I am trying to find hfe value of a transistor, I am taking inputs from ADC's ported to the microcontroller,Now i need to code division in 8051 the formulae will be

```
V1*10/V2
```

Can someone help me in coding this because V1*10 will be a WORD with msb in B and lsb in a.

Comment: What's the matter with having the value splitted in A and B registers???, what are u trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Divide by V2 and multiply by 10 after that.

Comment: then i will not get the precision, i'll only get multiples of 10 .

Comment: Then divide 10 by V2 and multiply it by V1